# What happens if a Person spent money on good things which are earned from bad ways

Tags: karma

Think That , a person is selling liquor or weapons , Now he has done the business some time and now he is a very rich person .

According to Buddhism Selling liquor and weapons are bad businesses .

Now he is spending money for good things ;)

Ex:- doing lots of charity work .

So now what will happen .

If he did more good things more  no harm will come for him ?

Can you explain me this :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem at all. It will have [mixed result (if casue is really mixed)](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.057.nymo.html) or each action will have it's own result (selling liquor - bad, generosity - good). Amount of the result is not just lineraly depend on the amount of action, it's also depend on the [level of development of mind](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.099.than.html) of the performer. There is more factors to play in the ripening of karma.